# Is there a non-exception way to access getDeclaredMethod?

Tags: java, reflection

I have two objects I might need to invoke methods on, and I won't know which one it belongs to coming in. Right now, my basic workflow is thus:

```
Method method = null;
Target target = null;
try {
    method = first.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, typeParams);
    target = first;
} catch(NoSuchMethodException e) { 
    try {
        method = second.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, typeParams);
        target = second;
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException e1) {
        // they sent us a bad command, return 404-esque response
    }
}
method.invoke(target, arguments);
```

I would really like to avoid all the exception handling like this, because not having a method isn't really an exception, it's an expectation. The ideal would be

```
if(first.getClass().hasDeclaredMethod(methodName, typeParams)) {
    return first.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, typeParams).invoke(first, arguments); 
}
if(second.getClass().hasDeclaredMethod(methodName, typeParams)) {
    return second.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, typeParams).invoke(second, arguments); 
}
// they sent us a bad command, return 404-esque response
```

What sorts of options are available to reduce the dependency on exceptions in this way? I'd prefer to not write "wrapper methods", as those can be cumbersome and difficult to tell when an error occurred or not.

Comment: You could list all declaredMethods and test them to check if one of them corresponds to the method signature you're expecting.

Comment: If you have Java9, maybe method handles could help. Like reflection, but checking happens only once at creation time. If that doesn't help, there is nothing else. Reflection is inherently error prone, thus potential exceptions all over the place.

Comment: @GhostCat is java.lang.invoke intended to be a modern replacement to java.lang.reflect?

Comment: I think @kumesana is where I need to go. I just built a cache of accepted methods on the first, and then on the second. I'll share my solution when I see how it runs. If you'd like to put an answer yourself with some skeleton code, I'd be happy to give you proper credit for it.

Comment: Handles are a way to give Java reflection without the permanent performance impacts. As said: handles are checked once at creation time, but using method objects results in the same checks taking place each time you use it.

Comment: Note that this almost certainly doesn't have the semantics you want (it excludes inherited methods); what's your reason for doing this in the first place? It sounds like an XY problem (at the least, using something like Groovy might be a cleaner solution).

Comment: @chrylis A request comes in from a client - the request might be handled by any number of different families of receivers - if the first in the chain can't process the request, it delegates it down the chain. The methods being called on the receivers (a decision outside of my control) must match a certain parameter in the request message.

Comment: If there's any option of using Groovy, this is simply `([first, second].find { it."$methodName"} ?: errorHandler) (params)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you don’t want to catch exceptions, you have to implement a search, i.e.

```
public static Optional<Method> getMethod(Class<?> decl, String name, Class<?>... arg) {
    return Arrays.stream(decl.getDeclaredMethods())
        .filter(m -> name.equals(m.getName()) && Arrays.equals(m.getParameterTypes(), arg))
        .findAny();
}
```

Which you can use like

```
Optional<Method> m = getMethod(target.getClass(), methodName, typeParams);
if(!m.isPresent()) {
    target = second;
    m = getMethod(target.getClass(), methodName, typeParams);
}
if(m.isPresent()) try {
    m.get().invoke(target, args);
}
catch (IllegalAccessException|InvocationTargetException ex) {
    …
}
```

though other ways to use optionals are possible.

You might be tempted to say “wait… but this does a linear search throughout all declared methods”, but well, no-one ever promised that `getDeclaredMethod(String, Class<?>...)` does something better than a linear search, and in fact, in the widely used reference implementation, it doesn’t. The search it does, has the same logic as the one shown above, besides throwing an exception at the end if no match has been found.

Even if it did, e.g. a hash lookup, the costs of creating a new exception might outweigh the costs of a linear search through a limited number of declared methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a custom helper method. Something like this should do:

```
static Optional<Object> invokeMethodIfPresent(Object target, String methodName, 
       Class<?>[] typeParams, Object[] arguments) {
    try {
        Method m = target.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, typeParams);
        return Optional.of(m.invoke(target, arguments));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

And that can be used in a relatively cleaner way:

```
return Stream.of(first, second, etc.)
          .map(o -> invokeMethodIfPresent(o, methodName, typeParams, arguments))
          .filter(Optional::isPresent)
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
```

Or using multiple objects: